# How to pass data from a React Native app to a PHP script?

Tags: php, react-native

I'm using this code to pass the userName variable...

```
return fetch('http://creat1vedesign.com/userTabs4.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
}, {
  body: JSON.stringify({
      userName: 'carolf'
  }),
```

...to this php script...

```
<?php
include 'DBConfig.php';
$con = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    $userName = $obj['userName'];
$sql = "select * from Users where userName = '$userName'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { 
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tem = $row;
    $json = json_encode($tem);
 }
} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

...to retrieve data for a specific criteria. But either the React Native is not sending the data or the php script is not receiving it or the syntax is incorrect or I'm doing something else wrong :(

Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't need a while loop and your query is open to SQL injection attacks.   Beyond that, are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your issue but I'd recommend using `$con->query($sql)` within your if statement because you're mixing procedural mysqli and oop mysqli.

Comment: Could you post complete fetch please?

Comment: you can use var_dump($_POST) for see what php is receiving from your react app.

Comment: no error message... I simply don't get any result from the select... changing to $con->query($sql) didn't help

Comment: complete fetch on my pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0cxQasd9

Comment: first check your server for CORS-domain. I've tried to post into your url and it blocks CORS-access; Second, try using Ajax or Jquery post function from your browser to validate your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters to the PHP script in the fetch URL by adding them after a '?' like this:

```
fetch("http://creat1vedesign.com/userTabs4.php?userName=carolf",{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })

      .then( (response) => {
            return response.json() })   
                .then( (json) => {
                    console.log(json)
                });
```

Just make sure to include a $_GET in your php script:

```
<?php

$userName= $_GET["userName"];

include 'DBConfig.php';
$con = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$sql = "select * from Users where userName = '$userName'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { 
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tem = $row;
    $json = json_encode($tem);
 }
} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```